# preact - how to get the current component instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, preact

Is there a way to access the instance / get a reference of the function Component that it is currently rendered/active in `preact`, an thus its current props, hooks, internal state, effects etc.?

I am looking for something like React's `__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner` (but consumable also in production) or Svelte's runtime internal `get_current_component()`.

To give you a bit of context, the reason why I need it is because I am building a library that provides a function that should be able to access the props of the Component currently consuming this function, in production and during runtime.

I was looking at `preact`'s source code, and I found that in `preact/hooks/src/index.js` there is a `currentComponent` global variable, but I couldn't understand how this is obteined. I have tried to play with `options`, or with `render`, imported from `preact`, but still couldn't figure out how to access the current component.

Is there any way to achieve it in `preact`, or is there any 'hack' to achieve something similar?

Thx in advance